# Prove that $|Im\{f(z)\}|≤ $$\frac{2}{\pi} \log \frac{1+|z|}{1 - |z|},$ $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function defined on the unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{z : |z| < 1\}$ so that $f(0)=0$ and $−1<Re\{f(z)\}<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that $|Im\{f(z)\}|≤ $$\frac{2}{\pi} \log \frac{1+|z|}{1 - |z|},$ $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

I want to use the fact that $Imf$ and $Ref$ satisfy maximum modulus principle (strong version.  But not sure if that is useful or not.  Would love some help.  Thanks